# iOs - unrecognized selector sent to instance on TextAction

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, alert

i've some problem with this error :

```
ProjectName.ViewController textAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa60bc3840
```

The error appears when i try to create an alerte. Here is the code :

```
@IBAction func trySearch(sender: UIButton) {
    self.api.getUser(self.textField.text!) { isResponse in
        if (isResponse.count == 0) {
//Still crash HERE.
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "This username doesn't exist", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            print("existing username")
        }
    }
```

If i comment all the alert code and replace it by a simple print it s works... I really don't understand why... Thank's !

getUser function:

```
func getUser(user: String, completion: ((isReponse: AnyObject) -> Void)) {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://********")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("Bearer \(self.loadToken())", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    Alamofire.request(request)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                completion(isReponse: JSON)
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
}
```

UPDATE : Same error when i click on "Done" of my TextField. + i add the getUser function.

Comment: Just a side note: By convention you should write function names in lower case `func search(sender ...`

Comment: She is in lower case in my code, just here i don't know why. Edited :)

Comment: Hey @Makaille, your code for alert in else block is perfect and it works without any issue.<br><br>I couldn't understood your code part

    `response in  if response.boolValue == true {
                /* ... */
            }
            else { }`

Comment: Hello, @AvinashJadhav getUser will return me true or false if user exist or not. If my user exist i ll do some things like prepare data for an other view etc, if not i just want to create the alert. is it more clear ?

Comment: `response in if response.boolValue == true {  }` is making a single line code statement and is looking incorrect. Because  `response in if { }` looks in correct. I thinks it should be like syntax `object in objectArray`which is loop execution. So make sure about same line is correct syntactically.

Comment: Make sure response is not nil

Comment: @AvinashJadhav reponse can't be nil

Comment: in getUser(), NSURL String is not double quoted...

Comment: @AvinashJadhav edit error :) don't worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

You may be in the wrong thread, since you are presenting the alert within a block, try:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { _ in 
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "This username doesn't exist", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: Why to put in asynchronous block?

Comment: @AvinashJadhav To execute it in the main thread instead of a background thread

Comment: There is no reason to force it to be synchronous, the important part is that it runs on the main queue

Comment: Hey @simpleBob, his code for alert works without any issue. I tried it on machine. I think issue may belongs to his `getUser` method call, if condition and response handling.

Comment: @AvinashJadhav if the issue really is because of the thread, you may not be able to reproduce it just by copy/pasting his code, since your code may be running on the correct thread

Answer (score -1):

handler 
A block to execute when the user selects the action. This block has no return value and takes the selected action object as its only parameter. 
YOU don't  assign action here.
Make like this:

```
UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                 actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                 {
                     //Do some thing here
                     [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                 }];
// add action to your alertController

[alert addAction:ok];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertAction_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIAlertAction/actionWithTitle:style:handler:

Comment: The handler is the response of a webservice request.